# Relationships disappeared - MS Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I have a split access database that's been in use for almost two years. The database resides on a computer which I access remotely via Remote Utilities, where I transfer the db to my local PC, work on it, then transfer back to the remote machine. We use EaseUS Todo Backups to create an image file every 30 minutes of the database file. I am currently in the process of doing some refactoring and have run into the following issue:

All of the relationships in the database have somehow disappeared. Here is what is strange about this:

- About a week prior to discovering this issue I had taken a copy of the database and did not have this issue.
- The relationships are gone whether I open it on my local machine or the remote machine.
- Upon finding this, the first thing I did was try to restore a backup to see if the relationships were there -- they were not.

This is what I can't figure out -- I had copied the file, everything was OK, then a week later no relationships were found in either the current copy, nor any of the backups from *before there was no issue.*

I have tried the following to resolve this:

- Updating Access on both machines.
- Hiding all tables then adding back and showing 'all relationships' in relationships tab.
- Looking for relationships in the database documenter.
- Restoring old backups as mentioned.

I'm sure this could be a result of corruption -- but how could this corruption extend to the .pbd image files generated by EaseUS, that were created before the issue occurred?

Comment: Did you set up your relationships in the frontend or the backend? Best practice is to only set up the relationships in the backend.

Comment: Relationships are only in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the All Relationships button.
2. Repeatedly click the Hide Table button.  Each click hides one table at a time.  Continue clicking until the Hide Table button grays out.  That will mean that you've hidden every last table.
3. Click the All Relationships button, again.  This will make all of the tables (with their connecting lines intact) reappear in rows of four-each, with all of your tables now visible.